# After running test case in Protractor, further test cases are not executing

Tags: protractor, ui-automation

```
describe('Login ', function () {

    afterEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

    });

    //1. First test case
    it(' through Account', function () {
        browser.get("URL");
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        var gmail = element(by.css('.ggl>img'));
        gmail.click()
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

            element(by.id("Email")).click();
            element(by.id("Email")).sendKeys('EMAIL');
            element(by.id("next")).click();
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.id("Passwd")).click();
            element(by.id("Passwd")).sendKeys('PASS');
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.id("signIn")).click();
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
            browser.sleep(20000);
        });
    });

    //2. second test cases

    it(' Enter', function () {

        var Encryption = element(by.model("password"));
        browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(Encryption), 100000);
        Encryption.sendKeys("click123");
        element(by.id("submit")).click();
        browser.sleep(10000);

    });
});
```

These are two testcases inside 'it'. But after successful login second test case is not working.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your first test you have
`browser.sleep(20000);`
It means it will wait 20 seconds before executing next test. Are you sure you want to wait that long?

`browser.wait` returns promise, so what you have to do is

```
browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(Encryption), 100000).then(function() {
    Encryption.sendKeys("click123");
    element(by.id("submit")).click();
});
```

Also you miss semicolon in `gmail.click()`

Comment: after fixing all these issues still unable to execute the second test case.

Comment: And if you comment everything, so you have two empty `it` blocks, do they run correctly?

Comment: @ FCin: yes if I comment out everything and eun empty it blocks then it runs correctly.

Comment: @RozmeenMomin and if you put `console.log('SECOND TEST');` at the beginning of your second `it`, does it show up? I just want to figure out the place where it breaks.